# Change position of the clearable 'x' in Dash Dropdown

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I'm quite new using Dash and I need to change the position of the small 'x' (take it to the top for example) when using a Multi-Value dropdown. The default positioning seems to be the middle, I assume, but when I have many values as input it's not useful to look for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the 'x' that clears the entire selection of the dropdown.

[image: x]

You can target this element with the selector `.Select-clear-zone` using css:

```
.Select-clear-zone {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

The default `vertical-align` value of `.Select-clear-zone` is `middle`.

If you want to align this at the top you probably want to align the caret at the top as well:

```
.Select-clear-zone, .Select-arrow-zone {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Result:

[image: new-x]

If you're actually referring to the 'x' on each dropdown item you can target `.Select-value-icon`

---

For including styles in Dash apps see the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources).

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help.. If I can ask you one more question. Would you know how I can include a "select-all" option inside the dropdown? I mean in case I use the 'x' to clear the entire selection or just delete some of them, to have an option to bring them all back.

Comment: @Emanon You can create a callback that outputs selected values on button click. So on button click (`n_click`) output options to dropdown `value`. I think this would be a good separate question, so I would create a new question post for that.

Comment: Yes I'll do it in a separate post to add some piece of code too cause so far I only managed to add a select option outside the dropdown and isn't that useful. Thanks